# making function in one file that multiplys two 3 by 3 matrices but it sees out first line correct then its wrong

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I did this program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 just like another person did it but when It sees out the resulting product matrix the first row of the matrix is correct but the other two rows below in the matrix are wrong

so it's seeing out this wrong matrix

5.3   23.9    24
-9.25596e+061   56.3   60.2
    416    497.1  2980.9

the correct answer/Matrix that my program should see out is

5.3   23.9  24

11.6  56.3  58.2

17.9  88.7  92.4

Because im multiplying this matrix1

1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9

by this matrix2

0    2    4

1    4.5  2.2

1.1  4.3  5.2

here is the code

```
// 
//
// 
//
//Purpose: program that multiplys two matrices

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



const int N = 3;

void multiplyMatrix(const double a[][N], const double b[][N], double c[][N]);


int main()
{
    const double matrix1[][N] = {{1, 2, 3},{4, 5, 6},{7, 8, 9}};               //matrix 1
    const double matrix2[][N] = {{0, 2, 4},{1, 4.5, 2.2},{1.1, 4.3, 5.2}};     //matrix 2

    double matrix[][N]= {0};

      multiplyMatrix(matrix1, matrix2, matrix);






     return 0;
}


void multiplyMatrix(const double a[][N], const double b[][N], double c[][N])
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for ( int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
            {
                c[i][j] += (a[i][r] * b[r][j]);
            }
            cout << c[i][j] << setw(7);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


}
```

please help

Comment: I seriously doubt this is doing what you think it is: `double matrix[][N]= {0};`. Try `double matrix[N][N] = {{0}};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you actually didn't allocate any memory for the result. the compiler cant understands you ment the result to be a 3x3 matrix when you declare :

```
double matrix[][N]= {0};
```

unlike this case :

```
const double matrix1[][N] = {{1, 2, 3},{4, 5, 6},{7, 8, 9}};
```

which the compiler "understands" as a 3x3 matrix.

change `double matrix[][N]= {0};` to `double matrix[N][N]= {0};` and your problem will be solved.

by the way, you had a segmentation fault/stack overflow since you had room for only 3 doubles but you used 9.

Comment: Thank you Thank you thank you! I Love you.                         Please though if you could explain what you meant by  "you had a segmentation fault/stack overflow since you had room for only 3 doubles but you used 9."  and if this refers to a mistake how I can correct it (specifically)
Thank you so much

Comment: for a statically defined arrays, the size of the entire array can be retrieved via the `sizeof` operator.using this data you can calculate the number of elements the array can hold : for `double matrix[][N]= {0};` you could have used `int numOfDoubles = sizeof(matrix)/sizeof(double)` which would have resolved to 3 (instead of 9 as you intended).